# TYPO3 menu barrier-free

Tags: menu, typo3, accessibility

I'm working on an new TYPO3 website and try to make this as barrier-free as possible.
Checking the site with a testing tool (wave) i get told that there is redudant text in the menu items. It says: "Title attribute text is the same as text or alternative text".
The generated code (boostrap_package) looks like this for example:
`<a href="/fach" id="nav-item-18" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" title="Fach" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="nav-link-text">Fach</span></a>`

I dont know how to change this. Can someone help me?

Comment: Does Fach really have a submenu? Bootstrap’s JavaScript usually requires also a `data-dropdown` attribute to make it work, and for accessibility (Barrierefreiheit) the menu item’s role should be `button`. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navs/#using-dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

The [WAVE tool](https://wave.webaim.org/) reports "errors" (red squares with a white X, [image]) and "alerts" (yellow triangles with a white exclamation point,[image]), among other things.

All results from WAVE should be inspected for accuracy but in general, "errors" typically need to be fixed (most of the time they're [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/) failures) but "alerts" might be a "best practice" and not necessarily a WCAG failure.

In this case, having a link with text that matches the `title` attribute will most likely cause a screen reader to say the text twice so it's flagged as an "alert" ([image]).  It's not great to hear the text twice but it's not a failure either.

```html
<a href="#" title="foo">foo</a>
```

Assistive technology, such as a screen reader, will announce the "[accessible name](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#dfn-accessible-name)" and optionally the "[accessible description](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#dfn-accessible-description)".  The description is normally announced with default screen reader settings but the user can turn it off.

The "accessible name" will come from the text inside the link, "foo" in my example or "Fach" in your example.  The "accessible description" will come from the `title` attribute.

You can see a list of various attributes that are used to computer the accessible name and description at [Accessible Name and Description Computation 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2).

In this case, the "accessible name" comes from step 2F, "[Name from Content](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#namefromcontent)" and the "accessible description" comes from step 2I (eye), "[Tooltip attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#dfn-tooltip-attribute)".

A screen reader normally announces the "accessible name" of an element, the type or role of the element, "link" in this case, and then the "accessible description".  So you'd hear *"foo, link, foo"* or *"Fach, link, Fach"*.

WAVE is just letting you know that hearing the text twice might sound a little wordy and redundant.  You don't have to fix it but it's worth considering.  A sighted user will see the text of the link and if they hover their mouse over the link, they'll see the same text in the tooltip. It doesn't really give the user any more information than they already have so the tooltip is kind of useless.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation!
My question is how to change the typoscript-code (see example above) so the redundant problem can be fixed

Comment: You didn't post any typoscript, just the HTML that typoscript generates. Are you creating the link with typoscript or are you using the CMS editor?